# PHP SOAP send Binary Security Token

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Buissness Flow

It has two steps
1. Authenticate user and get the binary certificate.
2. Use this certificate in header to communicate with other services.

USING PHP

Problem

I send my credentials to a service which returns me a binary certificate.

Then I use this binary certificate, encode it in base64 using base64_encode() method of PHP. Since I cant binary content in SOAP Request.

The output which I gets is much smaller and different certificate, hence my call to other services fails giving me a invalid certificate error.

USING SOAP UI for step 1

However when I use SOAP UI for the above flow, it works perfectly fine. As soap ui also uses base64 encoding (that I have found out).
PFB link
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781849515665/13dot-miscellaneous-topics/id286798206

I even tried to copy the certificate from SOAP UI and hardcode it in my PHP code. 
As SOAP UI shows the certificate in base64 encoding

Still call via PHP fails saying "Certificate is invalid".

I am clueless about the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is SOAP UI CODE

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cus="http://ccc/ddd/zzzzzz/jjj/service/serviceName" xmlns:java="java:ccc.ddd.zzzzzz.zzzzzzzzzzz.ccc.lll.zzzzzz.ctx" xmlns:java1="java:ccc.ddd.zzzzzz.zzzzzzzzzzz.ccc.lll.zzzzzz.tttttt" xmlns:java2="java:ccc.ddd.zzzzzz.zzzzzzzzzzz.ccc.lll.zzzzzz.cMode">
        <soapenv:Header xmlns:ca="http://ccc.ddd.zzzzzz.jjjj">
            <ca:AID>DataAID</ca:AID>
            <wsse:Security soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="XXXXXCertificate" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">Binary cintent in encoded format</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            </wsse:Security>
        </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <cus:opName>
             <cus:p1>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <java:ApId>
                   <!--Optional:-->
                   <java:Name></java:Name>
                </java:ApId>
             </cus:p1>
            </cus:opName>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Below is request from PHP Soap Client

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns3="java:ccc.ddd.zzzzzz.zzzzzzzzzzz.ccc.lll.zzzzzz.ctx" xmlns:ns2="java:ccc.ddd.zzzzzz.zzzzzzzzzzz.ccc.lll.zzzzzz.tttttt" xmlns:ns1="http://ccc/ddd/zzzzzz/jjj/service/serviceName" xmlns:ns4="java:ccc.ddd.zzzzzz.zzzzzzzzzzz.ccc.lll.zzzzzz.cMode"" xmlns:ns5="http://ccc.ddd.zzzzzz.jjjj" xmlns:ns6="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header>
            <ns5:CallerID>SE_SYS_1</ns5:CallerID>
            <ns5:CallID>1556549759</ns5:CallID>
            <ns5:ApplicationID>TEST_APP</ns5:ApplicationID>
            <ns5:CustomerID>LH</ns5:CustomerID>
            <ns6:Security>
                 <BinarySecurityToken>Copy pasted from soap ui in same encoding</BinarySecurityToken>
            </ns6:Security>
        </SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns3:sortCustomerList>
                <ns3:p1>
                    <ns1:ApplicationId>
                        <ns1:Name/>
                    </ns1:ApplicationId>
                </ns3:p1>
            </ns3:sortCustomerList>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What I am not using is EncodingType ans valueType etc in BinarySecurityToken tag while sending request via PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. As PHP cannot handle certain Unicode format that's why its `base64_encode()` function does not return the valid base64 string. 
A valid base64 encoded string ends with `=` or `==`.

Hence you might have to use your own encoder function which will convert Unicode to UTF-8
PHP users have submitted various function. One of the function from [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.convert-cyr-string.php) did the trick for me.

After getting valid UTF-8 use `base64_encode` function and you will get the correct BinarySecurityToken.

I used following code to convert it into valid utf-8 format.

```
function Utf8FromWin($str,$type="w")
{
    static $conv='';
    if (!is_array($conv))
    {
        $conv = array();
        for($x=128;$x<=143;$x++)
        {
            $conv['u'][]=chr(208).chr($x); //changed 209 to 208
            $conv['w'][]=chr($x+112);
        }
        for($x=144;$x<=191;$x++)
        {
            $conv['u'][]=chr(208).chr($x);
            $conv['w'][]=chr($x+48);
        }
        $conv['u'][]=chr(208).chr(129); // Ё
        $conv['w'][]=chr(168);
        $conv['u'][]=chr(209).chr(145); // ё
        $conv['w'][]=chr(184);
        $conv['u'][]=chr(208).chr(135); // Ї
        $conv['w'][]=chr(175);
        $conv['u'][]=chr(208).chr(151); // ї changed 209 to 208
        $conv['w'][]=chr(191);
        $conv['u'][]=chr(208).chr(134); // І
        $conv['w'][]=chr(178);
        $conv['u'][]=chr(208).chr(150); // і changed 209 to 208
        $conv['w'][]=chr(179);
        $conv['u'][]=chr(210).chr(144); // Ґ
        $conv['w'][]=chr(165);
        $conv['u'][]=chr(210).chr(145); // ґ
        $conv['w'][]=chr(180);
        $conv['u'][]=chr(208).chr(132); // Є
        $conv['w'][]=chr(170);
        $conv['u'][]=chr(208).chr(148); // є changed 209 to 208
        $conv['w'][]=chr(186);
        $conv['u'][]=chr(226).chr(132).chr(150); // №
        $conv['w'][]=chr(185);
    }
    if ($type == 'w') { return str_replace($conv['u'],$conv['w'],$str); }
    elseif ($type == 'u') { return str_replace($conv['w'], $conv['u'],$str); }
    else { return $str; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$certificateContent = file_get_contents($certificateCAcer);
$certificatePemContent =  '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----'.PHP_EOL
    .chunk_split(base64_encode($certificateCAcerContent), 64, PHP_EOL)
    .'-----END CERTIFICATE-----'.PHP_EOL;
```

to convert your binary certificate in base64 encoded structure.